# Смена отображающегося ViewController iOS Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios

Здравствуйте. У меня есть один Storyboard, в котором есть два экрана, для каждого экрана у меня есть отдельные классы ViewController. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки на первом экране показывался второй. Нигде не могу найти нужную функцию для смены экрана. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Ну посмотрите может это поможет](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxMv4OoE9jw)

Comment: Да, спасибо больше, это то что мне нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Просто киньте связь с кнопки на вторую вьюху,вот и все.(предварительно соответственно сделайте навигэйшен контролер.)

Ну и соответственно делегаты и `KVM` желательно знать:)

Насколько я помню напрямую использовать методы из другого класа можно только с помощью делегатов например так: [Example for delegate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm)

А передавать данные с помощью `KVO`, например так: [Objective-C биндинги](http://touchdev.ru/documents/2551)

Answer (score 1):

Можно кнопоке указать например вот такого рода метод

```
- (void)showNewController
{
UINavigationController *contactNavController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoardID"];
 ContactsViewController *vc =(ContactsViewController*)contactNavController.topViewController;
[self presentViewController:contactNavController animated:YES completion:Nil];
 }
```

не забыть тому окну которое вызывается задать StoryBoard Id